# Close a split screen/window in iterm

Tags: iterm2, iterm

Does anyone know what the shortcut (if it exists) to close an active pane in iterm.

I am using the beta version 2.9 and have tried configuring it in preferences to no avail.

This is what I have so far:

```
Shift + cmd + d = split pane (horizontally)
cmd + d = split pane (vertically)

Close pane = ??
```

Answer (score 38):

The answer is YES.
There is a shortcut <kbd>CMD⌘</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> to close pane in iterm2.

and Shift + <kbd>CMD⌘</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> closes the active window with all panes and tabs.

Comment: NB: ⌘ + W also closes tabs

Answer (score 5):

To close a split pane, focus the pane, and press:

<kbd>CMD⌘</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>

It also works for tabs.